# SSTP VPN Windows XP SP 3

Tags: windows, администрирование, vpn

Как подключить SSTP VPN на Windows XP SP3? Официально не поддерживается, может есть клиент? Как решить проблему без установки более новой ОС?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно купить роутер или установить его на виртуалку. Удаленную сеть забрать маршрутом на этот роутер.

CHR от Микротик бесплатно работает со скоростью 1мегабит